# C# Change Method Modifier of nested Class

Tags: c#, nested, modifier

I want to figure out if this is possible:
I have a class

```
class Class
{

    private Person person = new Person();
    public void NamePerson()
    {
        person.Name = "Peter";
    }

    public Person CPerson
    {
        get
        {
            return person;
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { set; get; }
    }
}
```

Inside of `Class` I want to have full access of the `person` object.
But having a write access of `Person` outside of `Class`

```
 Class a = new Class();
 a.CPerson.Name = "Steve"; !!!!!
```

should be invalid. I only want to have a read access.

```
string name = a.CPerson.Name;
```

Is there a way to do this in C#???
Thank you!

Comment: You are right, I also could define class Person outside of Class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an interface for that:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class Person : IPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now inside of class, you reference the object as `Person`, but only return an instance of `IPerson`:

```
class Class
{
    private Person person = new Person();
    public void NamePerson()
    {
        person.Name = "Peter";
    }

    public IPerson CPerson
    {
        get
        {
            return person;
        }
    }    
}
```